# PySide callback function not working in qml

Tags: qt, callback, pyside

I am new to PySide and I am trying to adopt this tutorial to my usecase:
[Selectable list of Python objects in QML | Qt Wiki | Qt Project](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Selectable-list-of-Python-objects-in-QML)

When I pass a callback function and call it from qml MouseArea, I get this error:
`TypeError: Result of expression 'model.on_select' [QVariant(PySide::PyObjectWrapper)] is not a function.`

Here is my model item class (or what is referred to as `ThingWrapper` in the tutorial):

```
class QtPasswdItem( QtCore.QObject ):

    # other stuff      

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def on_select( self ):
        print 'User clicked on:'
```

Here is the code setting the model for QML:

```
    passwd_model = QtPasswdModel( [QtPasswdItem( {c: '%s%02d' % ( c, i )
        for c in QtPasswdItem.COLUMNS } ) for i in xrange( 1 )] )

    qtrc = qtview.rootContext()
    qtrc.setContextProperty( 'passwd_model', passwd_model )

    qtview.setSource( path_qml_main )
```

And here is my QML code:

```
import QtQuick 1.0

ListView {
    id: passwd_list
    width: 800
    height: 600

    model: passwd_model

    // other stuff

    delegate: Component {
        Rectangle {

            // other stuff

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: { model.on_select() }
            }

            // other stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I correctly understand what you are trying to do, you should access your item method `on_select()` by calling `modelData.on_select()` from the delegate.

Comment: It didn't work. I am basing my call on the code in the tutorial. It seems like it my syntax should work but it doesn't and I am not sure why and what I am missing.

Comment: My last arrow on this case: you expose your model in QML by a context property under the name `passwd_model`. Try calling `on_select` on it

Comment: nope, that didn't work either.